# how to maintain lastaccesstime using manifold cf

Tags: lastaccesstime, manifoldcf

I am using manifold cf based windows fileshare connector to crawl files.
But Manifold CF also updates the lastAccessTime of all files that it reads.

I want to read all files without updating their lastAccessTime.

Which files in Manifold CF I need to update and how to achieve this?

Comment: without 'lastAccessTime' manifold has to re-index all your contents each time it crawls your repository. is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, i was able to do the sme usign google JCIFS

Answer (score 0):

[ManifoldCF](https://manifoldcf.apache.org/) does currently not maintain the last access timestamps for shared files crawled with its SharedDriveConnector. It uses [jcifs](https://jcifs.samba.org/) which has no support for reading or restoring the last access timestamp of touched files.

However, as you already noticed, the Google Search Appliance (GSA) somehow manages to keep the last access timestamps. So it should also be possible for ManifoldCF.

In version 3 of the GSA, its filesystem connector relied on a patched version of jcifs. (see [github.com/googlegsa/filesystem.v3](https://github.com/googlegsa/filesystem.v3))
And the release notes of that version indicate, that the connector was able to keep the timestamps too. (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/googlegsa/filesystem.v3/blob/master/projects/file-system-connector/RELEASE_NOTES))

So ManifoldCF might be patched to also keep the last modified timestamp, by using the patched version of jcifs from google. The best way to discuss something like this further is to post this requirement to the manifoldcf mailing list **user@manifoldcf.apache.org** or by opening a feature request in the [Issue Tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONNECTORS)

**Update 2017-07-13**
The Feature was discussed in [CONNECTORS-1429](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONNECTORS-1429) and will not be implemented.

---

An interesting fact is, that in version 4, the GSA went away from jcifs. Instead the GSA connector relies on native windows facilities.

Another sidenote: In order to be able to update a last access timestamp, the user used for crawling needs the *Write basic attributes* permissions. (see [GSA documentation](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/de//support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/connectors/40/410/DeployingtheConnectorforFileSystems.pdf))